# Drawing bar between 2 variable values with 3 groups in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have following data:

```
> mydf
  name grp var1 var2
1   aa   x  120   80
2   bb   x  128   86
3   cc   x  132   98
4   aa   y  125   85
5   bb   y  130   88
6   cc   y  138   99
7   aa   z  127   87
8   bb   z  132   89
9   cc   z  138  102

> dput(mydf)
structure(list(name = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "aa", "bb", "cc", "aa", 
"bb", "cc"), grp = c("x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "z", 
"z"), var1 = c(120L, 128L, 132L, 125L, 130L, 138L, 127L, 132L, 
138L), var2 = c(80L, 86L, 98L, 85L, 88L, 99L, 87L, 89L, 102L)), .Names = c("name", 
"grp", "var1", "var2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

I want to create a graph similar to following (which is manually drawn and not accurate to scale; the numers are all wrong here):

[image]

How can this be done (preferably with ggplot)? Colors can be any. The bar widths need to be the same (black bar is looking wider here since it is a manually created graph). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you might go about doing it with `base` R:

1. Choose some colours for your groups.

   ```
   colrs <- c('#66c2a5', '#fc8d62', '#8da0cb')
   ```
2. Add some space to the right of your plot, and extend clipping to the figure region, to allow plotting of the legend.

   ```
   par(mar=c(5.1, 4.1, 4.1, 6.1), xpd=TRUE)
   ```
3. Set up the plot area. The default `ylim` for `barplot` is a little tight for my liking, and will make text labels of your maxima/minima difficult. To deal with this, we first generate a redundant plot of the minima and maxima so that more generous y-limits are calculated. The `barplot` call can now use `par('usr')` to control y-axis limits. Assigning the outcome of `barplot` to `p` ensures that the bars' midpoints are saved.

   ```
   plot(unlist(mydf[, 3:4]), type='n', axes=FALSE, xlab='', ylab='', las=1)
   p <- barplot(xtabs(var1 ~ grp + name, mydf), beside=TRUE, col=NA, border=NA,
                las=1, ylim=par('usr')[3:4], axes=FALSE)
   ```
4. Add a legend, with a negative inset to prevent overlap with bars.

   ```
   legend('topright', unique(mydf$grp), fill=colrs, inset=c(-0.15, 0))
   ```
5. plot the bars with `rect`. The default width of bars plotted by `barplot` is `1`, so we can subtract and add 0.5 from the midpoints (stored in `p`) as necessary.

   ```
   rect(p - 0.5, mydf$var2, p + 0.5, mydf$var1, col=colrs)
   ```
6. Tidy up with a box and add the y-axis.

   ```
   box()
   axis(2, las=1, at=pretty(range(mydf[, 3:4])))
   ```

[image]

7. If you want to add text labels indicating the bar end values, you can use `text`.

   ```
   text(p, mydf$var2, mydf$var2, adj=c(0.5, 1.2), cex=0.9)
   text(p, mydf$var1, mydf$var1, adj=c(0.5, -0.2), cex=0.9)
   ```

[image]